# Is there any way to get the foursquare venue id of a place given an Instagram location id?

Tags: api, foursquare, instagram

Instagram locations are selected from a list of foursquare venues, and it's definitely possible to search for Instagram locations given a foursquare venue id, but I have an Instagram post and would like to find the foursquare venue it corresponds to - is this possible?

Comment: This would be very useful, any progress @tvachon?

Comment: When you say you have an Instagram post, do you mean you have the post info from the Instagram API? Or just the name of a venue by looking at a post on the Instagram app/site?