# How can I get more data about an Instagram location-id?

Tags: facebook, location, instagram, foursquare, instagram-api

In my calls to the Instagram APIs, sometimes I'll get location data like this:

```
{"id":641410285}
```

As I understand it, that's an Instagram location id; I don't know what that really means - who assigned the number? How is it managed, and all that sort of thing.  Is that documented anywhere?  But, setting that question aside...

There is an API to get more detail about that id.  But when I call that API for this location, I get this:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "code": 200
  },
  "data": {
    "latitude": null,
    "id": "641410285",
    "longitude": null,
    "name": "Wendy's"
  }
}
```

So it's probably a Wendy's restaurant.  Or somebody's house whose name is Wendy.

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19283541/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-foursquare-venue-id-of-a-place-given-an-instagram-lo) which seems related, if not exactly the same question, and I have found some instructions about how to start with Facebook or FourSquare locations/venues and discover the Instagram location-id, but does anyone have a way to discover more about an Instagram location-id?

Thanks for any pointers!